# Keep VueJS snippet DRY

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following Vue HTML. I know this can be done with other modules but I prefer not to use unless it is needed. I have a select in a form the client fills out that has a `select` for the opening and closing times of each day. Obviously this can get redundant because I would be listing all the hours (every 15 min in my case) as `option`s 2 times for each day and 7 times for all the days. It ends up being a couple hundred lines of code...for a hour `select`... Is there a better way to keep this DRY? I prefer to keep it in Vue land. Or JS in method etc...

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <select class="form-control" v-model="newPost.hours.sunday.opens">
    <option value="" selected>Opens:</option>
    <option value="12:00am">12:00am</option>
    <option value="12:15am">12:15am</option>
    <option value="12:30am">12:30am</option>
    <option value="12:45am">12:45am</option

...etc...etc x7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a property with all of the times to your component:

```
data() {
  return {
    times: ['12:00am', '12:15am', ...],
  }
}
```

Then use `v-for` in the template to generate the options:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="newPost.hours.sunday.opens">
  <option value="" selected>Opens:</option>
  <option v-for="time in times" :value="time">{{ time }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing it as data property is possible but I think it would be better to calculate the time range base on the start time you're passing to your time picker component. You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to easily create the times with 15 Min. steps inside your component. So no need to manually create that.

Then you could also modify the closing drop-down so it only shows the time after the start time. Dynamically updated.

And to create the two time picker components loop over an array of days `['Monday', 'Tuesday', ...]` with `v-for`.

In the app component I've created the empty data model dynamically so you have the object prepared for each day.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/36yL6a99/).

```js
moment.locale('en');

const timePickerComponent = {
 props: {
   day: String,
    caption: String,
    options: Object
  },
  template: `
   <div>
     <select class="form-control" v-model="timeSelected" @change="timeChanged">
        <option value="">{{caption}}</option>
        <option v-for="time in times">{{ time }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
   return {
     times: this.createTimes(),
      timeSelected: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
   'options.start'() {
     this.times = this.createTimes(); // re-create times
    }
  },
  methods: {
   timeChanged() {
     console.log('changed', this.timeSelected)
     this.$emit('changed', {day: this.day, selected: this.timeSelected});
    },
   createTimes() {
     // 0:00am to 0:00pm
      const formatStr = 'hh:mm a';
      let start = moment(this.options.start, formatStr);
      let range = this.options.hours; // 8 hours
      
      let times = new Array(range*4+1).fill(start);
      console.log(start, times);
     return times.map((item, index) => {
       return (index > 0 ? item.add(15, 'm') : item).format(formatStr);
      });
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data() {
   return {
     days: [
      'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
      ],
     openOptions: {
       start: "12:00 am",
        hours: 24
      },
      closeOptions: {
       start: "12:00 am",
        hours: 8
      },
      newPost: undefined
    }
  },
  created() {
   this.newPost = this.createEmptyPost();
  },
  methods: {
   createEmptyPost() {
     let newPost = {};
      this.days.forEach((day) => {
        newPost[day] = {
         openingTime: undefined,
          closingTime: undefined
        };
      });
      return newPost;
    },
   closingChanged(val) {
     this.newPost[val.day].closingTime = val.selected;
    },
   openingChanged(val) {
     console.log(val);
     this.newPost[val.day].openingTime = val.selected;
      console.log(moment(val.selected, 'hh:mm a').hour());
      this.closeOptions.start = moment(val.selected, 'hh:mm a');
    }
  },
  components: {
   timePicker: timePickerComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="day in days">
    {{day}}:
    <time-picker :day="day" caption="Opens" :options="openOptions" @changed="openingChanged"></time-picker>
    <time-picker :day="day" caption="Closes" :options="closeOptions" @changed="closingChanged"></time-picker>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  
  <pre>
{{newPost}}
  </pre>
</div>
```